# What verb is used for "playing" a YouTube video?

Tags: vocabulary

I want to say that I played a YouTube video.

Would it be 开 , as in 我开了一个十分钟的中文词汇视频 ?
v

Comment: I don't think the sentence makes sense. What have you played, a video game? Or you posted/watched a video on Youtube?

Comment: @r13 In English when you "play" a video it means that you clicked on a video and the video started, so you are now watching and listening to the video, the video is "playing". It does not mean the same as to play a game.

Comment: For the type of video in this case, I suggest using the verbs "watch", "upload" or "broadcast" for clarity - 我看了(watched)/上傳了(uploaded)/播放了(broadcasted)一個中文字汇的视频, so not to be misunderstood as 我**玩了**一個中文could字汇的视频,

Comment: @r13 Thanks for the suggestion but just to confirm I do not mean watch, upload or broadcast. They are different concepts. No native English speaker would misunderstand my question.

Comment: So what exactly do you do with the Chinese vocabulary video when it is playing? Play a crossword game, a puzzle, or...? That's what I wanted to figure out in the first place.

Comment: After I play the video / when the video is playing / after the video has been set playing , I will lie down and close my eyes and listen to the audio as I try to fall asleep. I am not playing, the video is playing. For another example: while I am typing this I am listening to Spotify playing some music in the background, Spotify is playing music, I am not playing anything, I am simple listening to Spotify as it plays music.

Comment: Actually have you heard the word "Playlist" ? It is a list of songs or videos that you would like an app to play , the listener/viewer is not playing anything, they are simply listening/viewing while the app plays some content.

Comment: 放/播放 are well. 开 is more of emphasizing you clicked the link and start a new page. Letting the video begin is typically called 播放 in madarin.

Comment: "I want to say that **I played a YouTube video**."; "我开了一个十分钟的**中文词汇视频**(Chinese vocabulary video)"; "I am simple **listening to Spotify** as it plays music;"; "have you heard the word "Playlist" ?". I hope somebody can sort it out. Good luck.

Comment: @r13 Thanks r13 , the discussion was helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. My pleasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write it down on paper, it should be "播放," i.e., "我播放了一段YouTube视频";

If your context is to say something to somebody, it can be "看," i.e., "我看了个YouTube视频";

If you are a teacher and played the video with your student, you can use "放," i.e., "我放了个YouTube视频";

If you want to use "开" in this sentence, you may need to use it in future tense, i.e., "I am going to play a video," "我准备开个视频看看";

Furthermore, the context you use "我开了一个十分钟的中文词汇视频" should be like: you are watching the video, and at the same time, somebody asks you (beside you, via phone, via SMS, or IM, etc.), "你在干什么？ (What are you doing?)", you can reply to him, "我刚开了个视频."

Answer (score 4):

> I want to say that I played a YouTube video

我看了一个十分钟的中文词汇视频 = I watched a 10-minutes-long Chinese vocabulary video

我**播**了一个十分钟的中文词汇视频 = I **played** a 10-minutes-long Chinese vocabulary video

播 short for 播放 (play/ broadcast)

Answer (score 1):

I would use 打开instead of 开only

Answer (score 1):

I would like to use 录 or 发布 a video.

Comment: 录 = recorded; 发布 = released

Comment: @CathyDeng Thanks Cathy , but the meaning is a little different. I don't mean record or release.